# "Get" or "Take"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between ***get*** and ***take***? How to choose the correct word for a specific context(Ex: I wanna ***get*** this or I wanna ***take*** this)?

Answer (score 2):

*Take* implies removal, therefore you can successfully *take* something only if it's physically in front of you.  For example, if you are in the kitchen, you can take a cup from a cupboard in the kitchen, but you can't take it off the table in the bedroom until you're in the bedroom.

You can *get* something that's not in front of you - for example, getting groceries - you might have to go to the store first.  You can't take them off the shelf until you are there.  (You can emphasize the fact that getting something will involve a trip with *go get X*).

*Take* and *get* have additional meanings and generally they do not overlap.

- *Get X* can mean "change your state/position to X" - e.g. *get away*, *get out*, *you're getting tired*, *she got arrested*, etc.  *Take* doesn't work like that.
- *Get X* can mean "understand X" or "internalize X with your knowledge/intuition" - e.g. *yes, I finally get what you are saying*.  *Take* doesn't work like that.
- *Take X* can be used with a few things to mean "eat/do something nourishing/fun/refreshing/educating" - e.g. take a break, take your lunch, take the medicine, take a class.  It's not common to use *get* this way but possible because *get* means "obtain" (*take* is more synonymous with "remove").
- Both *get* and *take* have a number of phrasal overloads, e.g. *take over X* (conquer or assume ownership of X), *take out X* (kill X), *get over X* (stop worrying/thinking about X), *get at X* (annoy X), etc.